# Unir dos consultas de SQL Server en una sola

Tags: sql-server

Tengo que hacer estas dos consultas una sola

Consulta 1:

```
SELECT r.id_referencia
    ,t.id_tipo
    ,o.id_operacion
    ,p.id_provincia
    ,s.id_superfice
    ,pr.id_precio
    ,v.id_vendedor
FROM vendedor v
JOIN Inmuebles i ON v.nombre_vendedor = i.vendedor
JOIN referencia r ON r.id_referencia = i.Referencia
JOIN Tipo t ON t.nombre_tipo = i.Tipo
JOIN operacion o ON o.nombre_operacion = i.Operacion
JOIN provincia p ON p.nombre_provincia = i.Provincia
JOIN superficie s ON s.superficie = i.Superficie
JOIN precio_venta pr ON pr.valor_venta = i.Precio_Venta
ORDER BY r.id_referencia
```

Consulta 2:

```
SELECT i.fecha_alta
    ,f.id_fecha
    ,f.año
    ,f.mes
    ,f.dia
    ,f.marca
FROM (
    SELECT fecha_alta
        ,YEAR(fecha_alta) AS año
        ,MONTH(fecha_alta) AS mes
        ,DAY(fecha_alta) AS dia
        ,1 AS marca
    FROM inmuebles

    UNION

    SELECT fecha_venta
        ,YEAR(fecha_venta) AS año
        ,MONTH(fecha_venta) AS mes
        ,DAY(fecha_venta) AS dia
        ,2 AS marca
    FROM inmuebles
    ) AS i
JOIN fecha f ON i.año = f.año
WHERE i.mes = f.mes
    AND i.dia = f.dia
    AND i.marca = f.marca
```

Lo he intentado de esta forma:

```
SELECT r.id_referencia
    ,f.id_fecha
    ,t.id_tipo
    ,o.id_operacion
    ,p.id_provincia
    ,s.id_superfice
    ,pr.id_precio
    ,v.id_vendedor
FROM (
    SELECT fecha_alta
        ,YEAR(fecha_alta) AS año
        ,MONTH(fecha_alta) AS mes
        ,DAY(fecha_alta) AS dia
        ,1 AS marca
    FROM inmuebles
UNION
    SELECT fecha_venta
        ,YEAR(fecha_venta) AS año
        ,MONTH(fecha_venta) AS mes
        ,DAY(fecha_venta) AS dia
        ,2 AS marca
    FROM inmuebles
    ) AS fec
JOIN fecha f ON fec.año = f.año
JOIN vendedor v
JOIN Inmuebles i ON v.nombre_vendedor = i.vendedor
JOIN referencia r ON r.id_referencia = i.Referencia
JOIN Tipo t ON t.nombre_tipo = i.Tipo
JOIN operacion o ON o.nombre_operacion = i.Operacion
JOIN provincia p ON p.nombre_provincia = i.Provincia
JOIN superficie s ON s.superficie = i.Superficie
JOIN precio_venta pr ON pr.valor_venta = i.Precio_Venta
ORDER BY r.id_referencia
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

¿Existe alguna otra forma de volverla una sola?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que quiere decir unir?

Comment: gbianchi dejar las dos consultas como una sola

Comment: sin ver datos y una estructura te diria que no. no tienen ni un campo en comun

Comment: No tienes la misma cantidad de columnas en ambas consultas. Tomar en cuenta que deben ser del mismo tipo de datos.

Comment: No creo que tenga que ver con el error pero al `JOIN vendedor v` le falta la clausula `ON`